# Insert Ajax.Updater content before specific element using insertion parameter

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, insertion

I thought this would be fairly simple but it turns out not to work as I thought it would or should.

```
new Ajax.Updater('myContainer','/url/',{
   insertion: {before: 'anotherElementId'}
});
```

How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs for [`Ajax.Updater`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/):

> The `insertion` option takes one of four strings — `top`, `bottom`, `before`,
>   or `after`

You are passing an object literal, which is why it does not work. The element referred to by the first argument to `Ajax.Updater` is the one which will be modified. That's the whole idea of that method (as a shorthand instead of doing the insert manually in a normal AJAX request callback).

So I think what you were aiming for was this:

```
new Ajax.Updater('anotherElementId','/url/',{
   insertion: 'before'
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed that point entirely! I got confused by the way insertion works in other cases. Thank You!